# Could not find stored procedure 'msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to delete a Maintenance Plan JOB using SQL Server 2008 but keep receiving the following error:

```
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 4
Could not find stored procedure 'msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job'.
```

Any help to where I should start looking would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like somone deleted the `msdb` database thinking that it has no function.

Do a new installation of SQL Server 2008 somewhere, backup `msdb`, and restore it to your production database.

Comment: Make sure `msdb` is really gone before you do this. Otherwise you'll lose everything stored in the current `msdb`.

Comment: How would you go about verifying that the MSDB is indeed gone?

Comment: @Alex: Check if the SP exists in the MSDB database.  In Management Studio: system databases -> msdb -> programmability -> stored procedures -> system stored procedures.  If there's no sp_delete_job there, your msdb database has been damaged somehow.